# Solve the system: $\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{3}}=2$, $(\sqrt{2}-1)x+(\sqrt{3}-1)y=5-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> Solve the system: 
>   $\begin{array}{|l} 
>  \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{3}}=2 \\  (\sqrt{2}-1)x+(\sqrt{3}-1)y=5-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}  \end{array}$

So, I started by multiplying the first equation by $\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{6}$:
$\begin{array}{|l} 
 \sqrt{3}x+\sqrt{2}y=2\sqrt{6} \\  (\sqrt{2}-1)x+(\sqrt{3}-1)y=5-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}  \end{array}$

How can I solve from here?

Comment: Solve one equation for $x$ and plug that into the other equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Cramer's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule):
$$|A|=\begin{vmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt2}&\frac1{\sqrt3}\\ \sqrt2-1&\sqrt3-1\end{vmatrix}=\frac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt2}-\frac{\sqrt2-1}{\sqrt3}=\frac{1+\sqrt2-\sqrt3}{\sqrt6}\\
|A_x|=\begin{vmatrix}2&\frac1{\sqrt3}\\ 5-\sqrt2-\sqrt3&\sqrt3-1\end{vmatrix}=2(\sqrt3-1)-\frac{5-\sqrt2-\sqrt3}{\sqrt3}=\frac{1+\sqrt2-\sqrt3}{\sqrt3}\\
x=\frac{|A_x|}{|A|}=\sqrt2$$
Can you find $y$?

Comment: Thank you! I haven't seen Cramer's method before. If I do understand, in the beginning, you are writing the coefficients. What do you calculate after this?

Comment: Yes, $A$ is a matrix (table) of coefficients of $x$ and $y$. $A_x$ is a matrix with first column replaced by right hand side numbers. $|A|=\begin{vmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{vmatrix}=a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}$ is a determinant.

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable with linear algebra, you have a $2\times 2$ matrix which is invertible. If not, try solving for $x$ (or $y$) in the first equation and plug it into the second equation

Comment: Thank you! I don't know what a matrix is, so I guess I will solve for $x$ in the first equation and plug it into the second equation.